# Data in NSUserDefaults refreshes only after re-run application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

There are initial scene where `viewDidLoad` gets object from data and outputs its property into `UITextLabel`

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var data: NSData = defaults.objectForKey("testing1") as! NSData
    var payment: CPaymentInfo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! CPaymentInfo
    testLabel.text = "\(payment.paymentValue)"
```

At least I have one more scene that contains two `UITextFields` and `UIButtons`. I want to change data in `NSUserDefaults` and see new data on the initial scene after segue

```
    if sender as? UIBarButtonItem == saveButton {
        var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if discriptionField.hasText() {
            newPaymentItem = CPaymentInfo(value: valueField.text.toInt()!, discription: discriptionField.text)
        } else {
            newPaymentItem = CPaymentInfo(value: valueField.text.toInt()!)
        }
        var data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newPaymentItem!)
        defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "testing1")
    }
```

but when I press save button, new number in initial scene does't appear, only the old number, but if I re-run application, new number will appears.

As I got, `viewDidLoad` maybe doesn't launch after segue. Ofc I can set text label like this in the unwind method of the initial scene

```
    var sourse: AddPaymentViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! AddPaymentViewController
    var newItem: CPaymentInfo? = sourse.newPaymentItem
    if let new = newItem {
        self.testLabel.text = "\(new.paymentValue)"
        var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(new)
        defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "testing1")
    }
```

But is there a more **elegant and rational** way to set "testLabel.text"?

Comment: Are you doing `defaults.synchronize()` ?

Comment: You have to use synchronize in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `viewDidLoad` won't be called after unwind segue.
It's fine to refresh UI in `viewWillAppear` method or in the unwind segue.

Comment: I tried to use  viewWillAppear( ), but new number appears with changing of the old only after some time (about 0.5 sec).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't synchronize saved data. You have to call `default.synchronize()` method to write changes to storage.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize